# How to do an inductive definition over "booleans" in Isabelle

Tags: types, boolean, predicate, definition, isabelle

In Isabelle, I want to define operators that take predicates `'a => bool` and modify them based on the "inductive structure of predicates". For example, one might want to compute the [Disjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (DNF) on these predicates, e.g. `D (λ x. P x --> Q x) = (λ x. ¬ P x \/ Q x)`.

The problem here is that `bool` is not an inductive datatype. I have thought of two possible solutions:

1. Create an inductive datatype that allows me to define my operators on them. Give predicate (`P::'a => bool`) semantics for this datatype and then use it to prove the lemmas I want to check.
2. Prove the theorems for each one of the possible inductive cases. Then show a general case that uses all of the previous rules.

As a third option, I am (wishfully) hoping that a more experienced Isabelle user might enlighten my approach with a secret function/typedef that circumvents this "inductive issue". So the questions here are:

Are there any other simpler options? If yes, which ones? If not, do any of my approaches seem flawed or doomed?

WARNING: I gave as an example, the DNF, however, the general case where the operator does not necessarily preserve the truth value of the predicate is of more interest to me, e.g. `D` could do this: `D (λ x. P x /\ Q x) = (λ x. P x \/ Q x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HOL functions cannot look into the syntactic representation of their arguments. The reason is the substitution axiom, i.e., logically equal terms may be replaced in any context. Otherwise, one could define a function `D` satisfying `D (λ x. P x) = True` and `D (λ x. P x & True) = False`, which leads to a proof of `False`.

For a function like conversion to DNF, whose semantics in HOL does not depend on the syntax of the argument, one can still define such a transformation. For the DNF conversion, the semantic operation is the identity, i.e.,

```
definition DNF :: "('a => bool) => ('a => bool)" where "D = id"
```

Then, you can derive rewriting rules that actually perform the conversion. For example,

```
lemma DNF_imp: "DNF (λx. P x --> Q x) = DNF (λx. ~ P x | Q x)"
```

If you call Isabelle's simplifier with such a dedicated set of rules, you effectively get a conversion into DNF (although you will never ever be able to formally express in HOL that your set of rules works in all cases).

Very often, rules like `DNF_imp` are not enough to implement such a function. In that case, you can write a simproc in Isabelle/ML which triggers on `DNF _` terms and performs the transformation. Since you are stepping out of the logic, the simproc *can* look at the HOL syntax of the argument and behave differently for logically equal terms.

Conversely, if you do want to express and reason about the conversion function `D` within the logic, there is no way around to introduce syntax to work on, as you have suggested with a datatype.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas for enlightening my understanding of Isabelle. Thanks to you I'll know better to try and find an inconsistency in the system. I just want to make sure I understand your last two lines: are you saying that ultimately we cannot reason about the "conversion function" within the logic? Or are you saying that in order to do so, I have to introduce the syntax? For most of last week, I understood it as the first meaning, however, now that I'm replying, it makes more sense the second meaning.

Comment: You can of course reason about the conversion function if you formalise the syntax within the logic. So the second meaning is the one I meant.